# Resolving conflicts with egit. No "Team -> Add" option

Tags: git, egit

I'm just started out with git and eGit with eclipse. So I created a remote repo on a linux server and from local computer #1 I pushed a git repo to the server. I pulled that repo to local computer #2.

Now I made a change and pushed that change from computer #1 to the server. I also made a change on computer #2 and when I tried to pull again from the server I got a conflict on computer #2.

I read in the egit user guide how to fix up the file until you've resolved all conflicts. Then the eGit guide says that I should do "Team -> Add" on the fixed files. But I don't have that option in my "Team" right-click menu. Below is a screenshot from the "Team" menu.

I'm sure this is something really obvious I'm missing here. Where is the "Team - Add" option located?

Thanks for help!

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find even where the freakin' team menu is. Not very intuitive IMO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In newer versions of eGit it's called "Add to index" according to eGit user guide:

> Click Team > Add on the project node. (This menu item may read Add to
>   Index on recent versions of Egit)